# implicitly convert std::shared_ptr to a type

Tags: c++, qt, shared-ptr, implicit-conversion

Let's say I have a class A which specifies conversion to int

```
struct A {
  int val = 42;
  operator int() const {
    return val;
}
```

so I can use it like this:

```
A a;
int a_int = a;
```

But what if I want to use shared pointer to the class:

```
auto a_ptr = std::shared_ptr<A>(new A);
int a_int = a_ptr; // ???
```

Just like the variable with type A was implicitly converted to int I want to do the same with a smart pointer.
How can I achieve that?

**UPDATE**

I'm sorry maybe I asked wrong way.
The real deal is a little bit more complicated.
I use QVariant to hold std::shared_ptr.
for now I have a helper function to do that:

```
QVariant & operator<< (QVariant& v, const std::shared_ptr<A> & aPtr);
```

When I need to place my pointer to QVariant I do this:

```
QVariant variant = QVariant() << a_ptr;
```

But I want to do it automatically, something like this:

```
QVariant variant = a_ptr;
```

Comment: Don't do that. Just write `*a_ptr`.

Comment: The new smart pointers works just like normal pointers, that includes things like dereferencing them.

Comment: overload of operators in most cases is bad engineering. Please avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

Its quite simple, use dereference operator:

```
int a_int = *a_ptr; // ???
            ^ ~~~
```

[Edit]

To make:

```
 QVariant variant = a_ptr;
```

Work, You would have to add to QVariant copy constructor accepting reference to shared_ptr. And this is something you cannot do.  Such statement is called Copy Initialization, first compiler tries to do conversion of a_ptr to QVariant and if it is available then copy constructor of QVariant is called with converted a_ptr. The problem is that even if you dereference a_ptr, there are two user defined conversions needed.

You can still add a cast like here:

```
 QVariant variant = static_cast<int>(*a_ptr);
```

Comment: I can't hold instance of A inside QVariant. It is too large. I need to place a pointer there. Whenever there is a statement that expects QVariant as a parameter I want to convert it to QVariant (and specify this conversion as I need, in some cases it can be rather complicated).

Comment: Well that changes things, from what I see QVariant can hold void* so maybe cast a_ptr.get() to void* and assign to QVariant?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it?
`std::shared_ptr` has the `operator*` and it works as one can expect: use it.

```
#include <memory>

struct A {
    int val = 42;
    operator int() const {
        return val;
    }
};

int main() {
    auto ptr = std::make_shared<A>();
    int v = *ptr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Just like the variable with type A was implicitly converted to int I want to do the same with a smart pointer.

No, you think you do, but you really don't.

> How can I achieve that?

You can't, and that's a good thing.

> (anticipating) Any way around it?

Wrap the shared pointer into an object, like this:

```
#include <memory>

template<class T>
struct shared_reference
{
  shared_reference(std::shared_ptr<T> pt) : _pt(std::move(pt)) {}

  operator T& () { 
    return *_pt;
  }

  operator const T& () const { 
    return *_pt;
  }

  std::shared_ptr<T> _pt;
};
```